# Replace NULL by default value in LEFT JOIN, but not in ROLLUP

Tags: mysql, join, rollup

I have a query having LEFT JOIN, group by and ROLLUP, like this:

```
Select * from
(
    Select user_agent,
    value,
    recoqty,
    count(recoqty) as C
    from august_2016_search_stats SS
    LEFT JOIN august_2016_extra E
        on (SS.id = E.stats_id and E.key = 'personalized')
    where time >= '2016-08-22 00:00:00' and
          time <= '2016-08-22 23:59:59' and
          query_type = 'myfeed' and
          recoqty = 'topics'
    group by recoqty,
             user_agent,
             value
    with ROLLUP
    having recoqty is not null
) D
order by C desc;
```

which gives result like this:

```
+------------+-------+---------+------+
| user_agent | value | recoqty | C    |
+------------+-------+---------+------+
| NULL       | NULL  | topics  | 1330 |
| abscdef    | NULL  | topics  | 1330 |
| abscdef    | NULL  | topics  | 1285 |
| abscdef    | 1     | topics  |   25 |
| abscdef    | 0     | topics  |   20 |
+------------+-------+---------+------+
```

Here, the value (`NULL 1285`) is due to LEFT JOIN, and the value (`NULL 1330`) is due to rollup.
However, is there a way to replace `NULL` value ONLY for `LEFT JOIN` and not for `ROLLUP` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky, because it appears that the `NULL` values coming from your data are indistinguishable from the `NULL` values coming from the rollup.  One possible workaround is to first do a non-aggregation query in which you replace the `NULL` values from the `value` column with `'NA'`, or some other placeholder, using `COALESCE`.  Then aggregate this as a subquery using `GROUP BY` with rollup.  Then the `NULL` values in the `value` column will with certainty be from the rollup and not your actual data.

```
SELECT t.user_agent,
       t.value,
       t.recoqty,
       t.C
FROM
(
    SELECT user_agent,
           COALESCE(value, 'NA') AS value
           recoqty,
           COUNT(recoqty) AS C
    FROM august_2016_search_stats SS
    LEFT JOIN august_2016_extra E
        ON SS.id = E.stats_id AND
              E.key = 'personalized'
    WHERE time >= '2016-08-22 00:00:00' AND
          time <= '2016-08-22 23:59:59' AND
          query_type = 'myfeed' AND
          recoqty = 'topics'
) t
GROUP BY t.recoqty,
         t.user_agent,
         t.value
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING t.recoqty IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What happens when you run the above query?

Comment: All NULL values got replaced by NA

Comment: Use `COALESCE` first, then subquery and do the rollup.

Comment: You should include sample data.  I can't debug anything without this.